# How to retain colorscheme in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a problem trying to retain the colorscheme I want in Vim. I have tried the command

```
colo colorscheme
colors colorscheme
colorscheme colorscheme
```

But none of them worked. When I reopened my file, a default colorscheme was still used. 
Pic1 is with the default colorscheme
Pic2 is with delek which is the one I want
Pic3 is the screenshot of _vimrc

[image]

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

[image]

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Try moving the *colorscheme delek* line to the end your _vimrc.

Comment: Still doesn't show up haha

Comment: Do you have the line `syntax on` in your vimrc, I don't see it? Have you tried starting vim with a vimrc containing only the lines `syntax on` and `colorscheme delek`? You can do that with `vim -u test.vimrc` where `test.vimrc` contains only the 2 lines I mentioned before. If that solves the problem you're good to [debug your vimrc](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: Where should I add syntax on?  The file is _vimrc  :)

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved :)